# Listing a valid and non-empty zip object prints empty list

Tags: python, list

`zip_obj` is a zip object containing 17292 tuples. A weird thing is happening with it:

```
sorted_zip_obj = sorted(zip_obj, key=lambda x: -abs(x[1]))
print(f'{len(list(zip_obj))} {len(sorted_zip_obj)}')
```

prints `0 17292`. How come this happens? **Why the first number printed is 0 and not 17292?**

`zip_obj` is something that I am retrieving from somewhere else and unfortunately cannot share, and I cannot reproduce this behavior in small zip objects that I manually create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on python 3, `zip_obj` is probably a lazy zip object which you can iterate over only once. You've already exhausted it when you sorted it.

Try realizing it into a data structure like this:

```
zip_obj = tuple(zip_obj) # you can use `list` if you prefer
sorted_zip_obj = sorted(zip_obj, key=lambda x: -abs(x[1]))
print(f'{len(zip_obj)} {len(sorted_zip_obj)}') # removed the redundant `list`
```

before using it.

From the docs for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.